# How to add symbols from statically linked library to a particular section in linker script

Tags: c, linker, linker-scripts

Let's say I have a section in a linker script that describes some really fast ram:

```
    .fastram __fastram_start : AT (__fastram_lma)
    {
        __fastram_start__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
        *(.fastram.fastram*)
        *fastram.*(.text* .data*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fastram_end__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
    } >fastram = 0x00
```

Normally we can do : `__attribute__((section(".my_awesome_section"))) void do_something()` and expect that the function will end up in that section. But what if I have a third party library I'm statically linking against and I want some of it's symbols to go into this fast ram section without modifying the original library? Is that possible?

So far I've tried redeclaring the functions I want added to this section with the same signature but with the attribute. But when I objdump it, my symbols are not where I want them to be.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229281/gcc-linker-move-a-symbol-in-a-specified-section answer your question?

Comment: Possibly. It could be a solution, but can I do something with the linker script instead? I'm linking libsomelib.a to my elf file so it might be a pain to do it with compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't directly answer the question, the solution I'm using to solve my issue is to patch the library using `FetchContent_Declare`'s `PATCH_COMMAND` from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718516/modifying-or-injecting-headers-after-fetching-a-git-repo-using-fetchcontent) and adding the attributes to the source that way.